# how does interelectrode capacitance reduces bandwidth?

Tags: semiconductors

How does inter-electrode capacitances reduces the bandwidth of operation in electronics devices? I am assuming that if capacitance increases the time constant of charging of that capacitance will also increase and this will the rise time. And as BW is inversely proportional to rise time it would reduce. But I am not sure of this explanation. Please confirm on this.   Moreover I would also like to know the relation of frequency and capacitance. As I understood from an explanation in a book, it seems as if capacitance is always there. Its only that at high frequency its reactance reduces and it acts as a short circuit. But that doesn't seem to be convincing. How does actually a high frequency signal causes capacitance to build up or in other words causes charge storage?

Comment: What do you mean by "electrode"?

Answer (score 3):

Think of a capacitor as a bucket you can fill with charge. It's not so far fetched; the first capacitors were glass jars lined with metal foil (Leyden jars) and until the 1920s, capacitance was measured in "jars" (1 jar is about 1100pf!)

The book is correct - the capacitance is always there and frequency has nothing to do with it. However the charge it can store is proportional to voltage (as if charge was a gas you could compress, not a liquid. And indeed voltage used to be called "pressure".)

```
Q (charge) = C * V.
```

But now consider an AC voltage across the capacitor. In one AC cycle, you fill the bucket, and then empty it. You have transferred charge Q out of the voltage source.

Now the more often you do that, the more charge you transfer in a second.  Charge per second is simply current, so the higher the frequency, the higher the current.

Current through the capacitance increases with frequency - so the "bucket" conducts better - i.e. its conductance is proportional to frequency - but the capacitance is the same.

Reactance is the inverse of conductance, so reactance decreases with frequency.

(The pedant will note that I should have used the word "susceptance" in place of "conductance" here;

```
susceptance = 1/reactance
conductance = 1/resistance
```

and for completeness,

```
admittance = 1/impedance
```

but I think that would only have obscured the basic idea)

Comment: so you mean, the terminals of electrodes acts as walls of bucket!

Comment: No, the terminals are more like the mouth of the bucket, or inlet and outlet pipes.

Comment: and where/what in that sense/analogy is the part where this water(charge) is stored?

Comment: In the bucket! It's only a crude analogy, don't focus on the bucket; focus on a fixed quantity of charge being transferred in each cycle and how frequency (cycles per second) affects the resulting current.

Answer (score 0):

Put simply, capacitance (capacitors) short higher frequencies. Those capacitances shunt your signal to ground and supply, to other signals, etc. thus attenuating it, and what can be even worse, creating oscilations and other evil side effects.

Answer (score -2):

frequency indirectly propostional to capacitance I.e., f=1/2XcC where Xc is reactance of the capacitor .if capacitace increases frequency decreases then bandwidth also decreased

Comment: At best, this is only an indirect answer to the question, but it's too vague to be sure. Please be more specific about how the capacitance reduces the bandwidth. Also, proofread your formula...